# How can I add image dynamically to the radio button text in jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am a quiz application using JQuery mobile. Each question will have 4 options(radio button). If the user selected correct option, then I need to display right icon next to the option. If the selected option is wrong, then I need to add wrong icon next to that selected option and right icon next to the right answer. Please help me how I can implement this in Jquery mobile?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/44EFc/)**

In the radio button markup, the label includes the images which are hidden with the class 'hide':

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" class="question">
<legend>Question 1:</legend>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-v-2" id="radio-choice-v-2a" value="A" />
    <label for="radio-choice-v-2a">Answer A <img class="correct hide" src="http://iconizer.net/files/C9d/orig/check.png" /> </label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-v-2" id="radio-choice-v-2b" value="B" />
<label for="radio-choice-v-2b">Answer B <img class="wrong hide" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/perfect-flat-icons-2/24/Delete_remove_close_exit_trash_cancel_cross.png" /></label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-v-2" id="radio-choice-v-2c" value="C" />
<label for="radio-choice-v-2c">Answer C<img class="wrong hide" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/perfect-flat-icons-2/24/Delete_remove_close_exit_trash_cancel_cross.png" /></label>
```

```
 .hide {
    display: none;
}
```

The script handles the change event on the radio button. It shows the correct image no matter which answer is clicked and then if a wrong answer is clicked, it shows the wrong image for that answer. I am showing/hiding by adding/removing the hide class.

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#page1", function(){
    $("input[name='radio-choice-v-2']").on("change", function () {
        $('.correct').removeClass('hide'); //show correct
        $('.wrong').addClass('hide'); //hide all wrong images

        var label = $("label[for='"+$(this).prop('id')+"']");
        if (label.find(".wrong").length > 0){
            label.find(".wrong").removeClass('hide'); //show wrong if wrong answer clicked
        }
    });
});
```